# Erro Ajax Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Bom eu tenho o seguinte código Javascript

```html
function fun() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'aposta.php',
        success: function(a){
            if(a) {
                a = JSON.parse(a);
                $("#tempo").html(a.time);

                if (a.time === 0) {
                    $('#oi').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#oi').removeAttr('disabled');
                    }, 6000);
                }

                $("#box").animate({
                    'background-position-x': numero(a.numero)
                }, 500);
            }
            else {
                $("#tempo").html("0");
            }
        }
    });
};
  setInterval(function(){
  fun();

  }, 1000);
 </script>
```

O que pretendia era naquele setinterval que atualiza de 1 em 1 segundo colocar, um código html, para que esse código html seja atualizado sem necessitar de refresh caso eu der alguma mudança no site.

Basicamente, o que quero é atualizar essa variavel $saldo no php a cada 1 segundo sem ter que dar f5 no site.

COmo poderei fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: O que é que um erro no ajax, tem a haver com atualizar numero real?

Comment: Nenhuma das perguntas está muito clara, e os problemas parecem ser o mesmos(eu achei isso, talvez pelo fato de não estarem claras). Se você editar ambas, deixando mais claro o que quer, eu retiro o voto para fechar.

Comment: Vou editar, obrigado por me avisar diego.

Comment: Já editei Diego

Answer (score 1):

O setInterval não é ideal para essa situação, ele pode trazer os resultados na ordem errada caso por algum atraso na rede a resposta para uma requisição que foi feita depois chegue primeiro ou empilhar um monte de requisições juntas.

Você pode solicitar o resultado da url passando uma função de callback para ficar mais organizado:

```
function requestMyServerData(){
    //a função abaixo chama $.ajax por dentro, 
    //simplifica para esses casos mais simples
    $.get('aposta.php', onResultReturned);
}
```

[jquery.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Então você implementa essa função de callback:

```
function onResultReturned(data){
    //aqui 'data' será a mesma coisa que 'a' no seu exemplo
    //pode tratar o resultado e então chamar novamente a primeira função
    //isso garante não fazer uma requisição antes da outra retornar
    requestMyServerData();
}
```

O ideal mesmo para esse tipo de situação é utilizar push, ou seja, fazer com que o servidor seja capaz de alertar o navegador do cliente quando houver uma alteração interessante para ele. Polling está ultrapassado.

Se você estiver utilizando um servidor IIS e .net, pode utilizar o SignalR para se comunicar com os clientes que estão com a página aberta no momento.
[documentação SignalR](http://signalr.net/)

Utilizando o apache eu não sei, mas deve ter algo similar.

Boa sorte!

Comment: Boa Tarde, n entendi mt bem, isso atualiza em tempo real?

Comment: Sim, o $.get é a mesma coisa que o $.ajax, só que com menos opções, só pra facilitar para quem não precisa configurar nada, só pedir o resultado de uma url, sem mudar nada de cabeçalho do pacote, etc... E você poderia declarar a função de callback dentro dentro do argumento da função do mesmo jeito que em cima, eu só separei pra organizar e explicar melhor